# How to add more column to "category product" grid of categories admin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

How to add more column to "category product" grid of categories admin in Magento 2.0.
[image]

If can, please show me step by step!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Oki, I'll answer my solution a minute.

Answer (score 1):

My solution below: Create new module "CustomPro" and some files noted below:

 **1) etc/di.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\CustomProduct" />
</config>
```

**2) Create file: Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\CustomProduct.php**

```
<?php
namespace Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product;

class CustomProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{

    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $productFactory, $coreRegistry);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter([
                'in_category' => 1
            ]);
        }

        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('period_date_start')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('period_date_end')
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getRequest()
            ->getParam('store'))
            ->joinField('position', 'catalog_category_product', 'position', 'product_id=entity_id', 'category_id=' . (int) $this->getRequest()
            ->getParam('id', 0), 'left');
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [
                'in' => $productIds
            ]);
        }

        // begin modify
        Extended::_prepareCollection();

        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumnAfter('status', [
            'header' => __('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'options' => ProductHelperData::getOptionStatus(),
            'type' => 'options',
            'sortable' => true,
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'renderer' => 'Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Options'
        ], 'entity_id');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**3) Create file: Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Options.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tohq\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Tohq\CustomPro\Helper\Data as HelperData;
class Options extends AbstractRenderer
{
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {


        $attributesArrays = HelperData::getOptionStatus();
        if (!empty($row) && !empty($this->_getValue($row))) {

            $value=$this->_getValue($row);

            if(!empty(HelperData::COLORS[$value])){
                $color=HelperData::COLORS[$value];

                return  sprintf($color,$attributesArrays[$value]);
            }

            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**4) Create file:Tohq\CustomPro\Helper\Data**

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Tohq\CustomPro\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Cms\Helper\Page;
use Monolog\Logger as MonologLogger;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler; 

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     *
     * @var STATUS_ONLINE
     */
    const STATUS_ONLINE = 1;

    /**
     *
     * @var STATUS_OFFLINE
     */
    const STATUS_OFFLINE = 2;

    /**
     *
     * @var STATUS_IN_COMMING
     */
    const STATUS_IN_COMMING = 3;

    /**
     *
     * @var STATUS_OVER_DATE
     */
    const STATUS_OVER_DATE = 4;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private $productModel;

    /**
     *
     * @return array|null
     */

    private $logger=null;
    const COLORS = [
        self::STATUS_ONLINE => "<span class='status status-online'>%s</span>",
        self::STATUS_OFFLINE => "<span class='status status-offline'>%s</span>",
        self::STATUS_IN_COMMING => "<span class='status status-in-comming'>%s</span>",
        self::STATUS_OVER_DATE => "<span class='status status-over'>%s</span>"
    ];

    /**
     *
     * @param Context $context            
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context)
    {
        $this->productModel = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);


    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getOptionStatus()
    {
        return [
            self::STATUS_ONLINE => __("Display Product"),
            self::STATUS_OFFLINE => __("Undisplay Product"),
            self::STATUS_IN_COMMING => __("Before Display Product"),
            self::STATUS_OVER_DATE => __("Overdate display Product")
        ];
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productData
     */
    public function changeProductStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product &$productData)
    {
        $status = $productData->getStatus();
        $typeId = $productData->getTypeId();

        $startDate = $productData->getData("period_date_start");
        $startDate = ! empty($startDate) ? strtotime($startDate) : 0;

        $endDate   = $productData->getData("period_date_end");
        $endDate   = ! empty($endDate)   ? strtotime($endDate)   : 0;

        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $datetime = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');

        $current = time() + $datetime->getGmtOffset();

        if ( $status == self::STATUS_ONLINE && $startDate == 0 && $endDate == 0 ) $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_ONLINE);
        elseif ( $status == self::STATUS_ONLINE && $current > $startDate && $endDate == 0) $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_ONLINE);
        elseif ( $status == self::STATUS_ONLINE && $current > $startDate && $current < $endDate ) $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_ONLINE);
        elseif ( $status == self::STATUS_ONLINE && $current < $startDate ) $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_IN_COMMING);
        elseif ( $status == self::STATUS_ONLINE && $current > $endDate ) $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_OVER_DATE);
        else $productData->setStatus(self::STATUS_OFFLINE);

        return $productData;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param unknown $collection            
     * @param string $status            
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function applyStatusFilterToCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection &$collection, $status = null)
    {
        if (empty($collection))
            return;

        $removed = 0;
        if ($status) {

            $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if (in_array($status, [
                self::STATUS_IN_COMMING,
                self::STATUS_OVER_DATE,
                self::STATUS_ONLINE
            ])) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', [
                    'eq' => self::STATUS_ONLINE
                ]);

                if ($status == self::STATUS_IN_COMMING) {

                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', [
                        'eq' => 'grouped'
                    ]);
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('period_date_start', [
                        'gt' => $today
                    ]);
                } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_OVER_DATE) {

                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', [
                        'eq' => 'grouped'
                    ]);
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('period_date_end', [
                        'lt' => $today
                    ]);
                } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_ONLINE) {
                    $nowTimeStamp = strtotime($today);
                    foreach ($collection as $el) {

                        if ($el->getTypeID() == "grouped") {

                            $_product = $this->productModel->load($el->getId());
                            if (empty($_product))
                                continue;
                            $dateStart = $_product->getData('period_date_start');
                            $dateEnd = $_product->getData('period_date_end');

                            if (empty($dateStart) && empty($dateEnd))
                                continue;

                            if (! (strtotime($dateStart) <= $nowTimeStamp && $nowTimeStamp <= strtotime($dateEnd))) {

                                $removed ++;
                                $collection->removeItemByKey($el->getId());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_OFFLINE) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', [
                    'eq' => self::STATUS_OFFLINE
                ]);
            }
        }

        if ($collection) {
            foreach ($collection as &$el) {

                $this->changeProductStatus($el);
            }
        }

        if (method_exists($collection, "reSetTotalRecords"))
            $collection->reSetTotalRecords($removed);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created a module and added the files and ran "setup:upgrade". I see the module in "Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced". But in the "category product" grid I don't see any new column or something that it is working. Do I miss something?

Comment: I have tried this but not working . can you share working code ?

Comment: This code is not working in Magento Enterprise Edition, Can anyone plz tell me how we can override Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Merchandiser\Grid.php